# Embedded video appears only when changing browser window size

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embed

I'm facing a strange video embed issue.

In any desktop browser (Chrome, Edge, etc.), I navigate to https://veganism101.com/faq-on-veganism-for-health/ and scroll all the way down to the question "Troubleshooting" and expand it.

On the right there's supposed to be an embedded youtube video (just above the caption: *Custom HTML Embedded Video*). But it's not there. But when I minimize/maximize my browser window or even slightly change the browser window size, the video appears!

I tried this on different desktop browsers, different desktop computers. Same issue. Surprisingly this issue does not happen when viewing on a mobile device.

This is the code that I'm using to embed the video.

```css
.codegena {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:0;
  padding-bottom:56.27198%;
}

.codegena iframe{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="codegena">
  <iframe width="560" height="329" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OwlGTVh06NQ?&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

I have no idea what is causing this. Very strange behavior.

Comment: @Dudi thank you for formatting the code to be more readable. Will keep in mind for next time.

Comment: no problem, bud. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @agent-biscutt for pointing me in the right direction. Tweaking the suggestion further, adding *!important* to the width and height of the iframe worked for me. The video shows and is responsive. I know it's not always best practice to use this in CSS, but feel like this was one of those cases. Anyway, this is how I tweaked it:

```
.codegena iframe{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your website, then there is one obvious problem.
When I go into developer controls, the video's iframe has a width and height of 0.
Fix this by amending the css:

```css
iframe{
    width: 602px;
    height: 337.12px;
}
```

If its not your website, not your problem, though you might wanna say something to the owners.

Comment: This does solve the problem of video not showing, but the responsiveness goes away. At least it's a step in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: No Problem zulu.